# Gradle DSL method not found: storeFile()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0. When I try to sync my Gradle file, I get the following error:

> Gradle DSL method not found:storeFile()

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "skripsi.ubm.studenttracking"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile (project.property("Students_tracking_keystore.jks") + ".keystore")
            storePassword "####"
            keyAlias "####"
            keyPassword "#####"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

A couple of things to note:

The `storeFile` DSL method has the following signature:

```
public DefaultSigningConfig setStoreFile(File storeFile)
```

i.e. it expects a `File` to be passed in. You probably need to place a `File` constructor in your code to ensure you are actually creating a `File` object. Because you're currently not passing in a file, Gradle is complaining that it can't find a method with the appropriate signature.

Secondly, you are currently appending two suffices to the filename: `.jks` and `.keystore`. You should only include one of these based on the suffix of the file you are referencing (it's probably `.jks`, but you should check to be sure).

In short, one of the following replacement lines will probably work for you:

```
storeFile file(project.property("Students_tracking_keystore") + ".keystore")
```

or

```
storeFile file(project.property("Students_tracking_keystore") + ".jks")
```

or

```
storeFile file(project.property("Students_tracking_keystore.keystore"))
```

or

```
storeFile file(project.property("Students_tracking_keystore.jks"))
```

Comment: where do i put the `public DefaultSigningConfig setStoreFile(File storeFile)` ?

Comment: You don't, that's the underlying java-style method that build.gradle is referencing.

Comment: So whats the solution for this ? i just want to build my application into apk so i can test it in real device.

Comment: @stkent just replace the line that contains `storeFile` in your `build.gradle` with any of the suggested codes above or simply type `storeFile file("Students_tracking_keystore.jks");` if the jks file is already located at the root of your project folder.

Comment: @ecle just saw this but I think your comment was aimed at the OP :)