# Gradle error - Could not find method storeFile() for arguments /path/to/storefile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have reviewed a number of posts on this topic,

- [Gradle DSL method not found: storeFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090337/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-storefile)
- [Sign APK without putting keystore info in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562189/sign-apk-without-putting-keystore-info-in-build-gradle)

for starters.  But I still cannot get past the Gradle error `Error:(69, 0) Could not find method storeFile() for arguments [/path/to/my.keystore]` on line 69:

```
storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
```

in the module gradle build file - contents of my module gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'signing'

android {

    ...

    buildTypes {

        ...

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
            def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
            keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']

        }

        ...

    }

    ...

}

...
```

where I load the `keystore.properties` file (located in project root), which contains:

```
storeFile=/path/to/my.keystore
storePassword=storepwd
keyPassword=keypwd
keyAlias=keyalias
```

As you can see, I have a file constructor in the storeFile reference in the gradle.build file and a path to the keystore in the properties file.

> **Where is the mistake, or what am I missing, not understanding?**

**Reference**

- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Gradle version 4.1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to add this DSL in the `signing` block not in the `buildTypes` block.

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']

        }
    }
```